# Change redirect url for Google provider in Strapi

Tags: node.js, reactjs, strapi

I just deployed my Strapi app on Heroku and now the redirect url is 0.0.0.0 on the Google provider. How do I change this?
[screenshot of Strapi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeuoM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the following docs: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/concepts/configurations.html#server

And configure your server.js (either `./config/server.js` or `./config/env/production/server.js`) and set the `url` key to that of your Heroku domain.